# Share an instance variable with another class

Tags: ruby

I have two classes:

```
class Zoo

  def initialize(visitor)
      @visitor = visitor
  end

  def elephant
      Elephant
  end

end

class Elephant

  def self.all
      [:e1, :e2, :e3].reject_if { |e| @visitor.has_seen?(e) }
  end

end
```

Obviously, the above example won't work.

Is there any way to express this, so that I can call:

```
Zoo.new(:visitor_1).elephant.all
```

and access `@visitor` inside an `Elephant` class method?

Comment: Not at all clear what you are doing.

Comment: Sorry if it's not clear, bottom line is that I want to be able to write: `Zoo.new(:visitor_1).elephant.all`. `Zoo` and `Elephant` need to be different classes and `Elephant` needs access to the instance variable `@visitor` in it's class methods.

Comment: There is no way to do this. One reason is Ruby doesn't allow instance variable access without an accessor or introspection; another one is, if you do `z1 = Zoo.new(:v1); z2 = Zoo.new(:v2); Elephant.all`, which `@visitor` should be looked up? I.e. how does an elephant know where it is? This makes no sense. If you gave us a real application that you need instead of a bad Zoo metaphor, we might be able to suggest an alternate design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing more about the models in your application, this is what you could do

```
class Elephant

   def self.all(visitor)
      [:e1, :e2, :e3].reject_if { |e| e.seen_by_visitor?(visitor) }
   end

   def seen_by_visitor?(visitor)
      # whatever code you need here to determine whether the given visitor has seen the elephant
   end

end

class Zoo

  def initialize(visitor)
      @visitor = visitor
  end

  def elephants
      Elephants.all(@visitor)
  end

end
```

Note that now `Zoo` depends on `Elephant`, but `Elephant` does not depend on `Zoo`.